# Text transformation and Datetime format issue on Linechart Zoom D3 V4

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to rotate x-axis text with the code below :

```
      focus.append("g")
          .attr("class", "axis axis--x")
          .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
          .call(xAxis)
          .selectAll("text")
          .attr("class", "x-axistext")
          .style("text-anchor", "end")
          .attr("dx", "-.8em")
          .attr("dy", ".15em")
          .attr("font-family", textfontfamily) 
          .attr("font-weight",textfontweight)
          .attr("font-size", textfontsize)
          .attr("transform", function (d) {
            return "rotate(-65)"
        });
```

Texts are rotating but only when the graph is not zooming. On zooming graph, texts are not rotating. Once you start zooming graph, new texts will be not in rotate position.

Next Problem i'm facing is related to the DateTime Format. Below line of code i'm using to format the text.

```
var parseDate = d3.timeParse("%H:%M:%S");
```

But it is also not working properly. Time are showing along with 'AM' 'PM'.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kwr089p7/6/): Here is the complete code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem 1**

*Time are showing along with 'AM' 'PM'.*

If you want the time on the ticks to come in a format please provide timeFormat:

`xAxis = d3.axisBottom(x).tickFormat(d3.timeFormat("%H:%M:%S"))`

**Problem 2**

*On zooming graph, texts are not rotating*

On zoom/brush you need to select all ticks and give rotation.

```
      focus.selectAll(".axis--x")
          .selectAll("text")
          .attr("class", "x-axistext")
          .style("text-anchor", "end")
          .attr("dx", "-.8em")
          .attr("dy", ".15em")
          .attr("font-family", textfontfamily) 
          .attr("font-weight",textfontweight)
          .attr("font-size", textfontsize)
          .attr("transform", function (d) {
            return "rotate(-65)"
        });
```

working code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/sa4h0vor/)

Comment: Thanks Cyril, Your solutions is working fine... This was the only way to do this..